# subsetting unique pairs

Tags: r

I have a list of currency symbols but they go together as a pair, and cannot be against its self. Below is an example:

```
ccy <- c("USD","EUR","JPY","GBP","CAD","AUD","NZD","CHF","NOK","SEK")
g <- expand.grid(ccy,ccy)
g <- g[g[,1]!=g[,2],]
```

*BUT* USD vs EUR, is just the inverse of EUR vs USD, or EUR vs JPY is the just the inverse of JPY vs EUR, so I would like to eliminate these from the `data.frame`.

Is there a programatic way of getting only the unique pairs from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `combn()`:

```
combn(ccy, 2)
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
[1,] "USD" "USD" "USD" "USD" "USD" "USD" "USD" "USD" "USD" "EUR" "EUR" "EUR" "EUR" "EUR" "EUR" "EUR"
[2,] "EUR" "JPY" "GBP" "CAD" "AUD" "NZD" "CHF" "NOK" "SEK" "JPY" "GBP" "CAD" "AUD" "NZD" "CHF" "NOK"
     [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32]
[1,] "EUR" "JPY" "JPY" "JPY" "JPY" "JPY" "JPY" "JPY" "GBP" "GBP" "GBP" "GBP" "GBP" "GBP" "CAD" "CAD"
[2,] "SEK" "GBP" "CAD" "AUD" "NZD" "CHF" "NOK" "SEK" "CAD" "AUD" "NZD" "CHF" "NOK" "SEK" "AUD" "NZD"
     [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45]
[1,] "CAD" "CAD" "CAD" "AUD" "AUD" "AUD" "AUD" "NZD" "NZD" "NZD" "CHF" "CHF" "NOK"
[2,] "CHF" "NOK" "SEK" "NZD" "CHF" "NOK" "SEK" "CHF" "NOK" "SEK" "NOK" "SEK" "SEK"
```

---

The function `combn` generates all unique combinations of length `n` from your input vector.

See `?combn` for more detail.